# Htaccess Redirect custom from query string

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to transform stuff like `index.php?videoid=1023286` to (custom link) like `/xxxxx/yyyyyyyyy`
in short

`index.php?videoid=1023286` becomes `/whateveriwant/whateveriwant2`
and it's custom queries only, what's happening is I changed the sef urls, the old urls are still working, and couldnt manage to fix them, anyway thats a different issue, but for now i hope to change only specific a videoid to a specific sef url :)

I looked all over the web and i could not find that.

Comment: Apparently "all over the web" did not cover Apache's documentation, which would be the first place for you to look for apache configuration options. ;) Here are some recipes for URL rewriting: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html

Comment: lol, well all over the web doesnt exist on the web either :D, thanks ill read that.

Comment: na, couldnt find what i exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create a keyword rich URL for SEO purposes with a format like http://www.yoursite.com/ANY-KEYWORDS-CAN-GO-HERE/dv/identifier   e,g http://www.yoursite.com/Help-Emma-Stone/dv/1023286  you can add the following code to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#rewrite http://www.yoursite.com/Help-Emma-Stone/dv/1023286 to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/dv/([0-9]+)
RewriteRule . index.php?videoid=%1 [L]
```

See this [post](http://ulrichpalha.com/myblog/2011/11/26/improve-your-sites-seo-with-basic-url-rewriting-redirects-using-mod_rewrite-in-htaccess/) for more details

Comment: no, thats now exactly what i want
i want to redirect urls from index.php?videoid=120938123 to category_i_choose/title_i_choose_custom_not_dynamic

Answer (score 0):

If you really only need that one single URI changed, this should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^xxxxx/yyyyyyyyy  /index.php?videoid=1023286 [R=301]
```

Keep in mind that you need to have mod_rewrite installed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for isn't going to be an htaccess-only solution.

First, you need something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

And the rest needs to be handled via PHP. You'll check to see that that category/title combination exists and then load it up internally.

To clarify that last part, I mean that you'll have to internally translate cat/title into the video id using a database.